# How to hide mat-input when disabled

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular reactive form. I am setting certain controls as disabled based on the value of another control. I would like to hide the controls when they are set to disabled. I'm assuming this needs to be done in CSS, but not sure how to do that.

```
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="1em">
                <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="floatLabel" fxFlex>
                    <mat-label>{{'audio.questions.Q1' | translate}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="q1">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let r of responses" [value]="r.abbreviation">
                            {{r.type}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="q1.hasError('required')">
                        {{'audio.questions.ResponseRequired' | translate}}
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>                    
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="1em">
                <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="floatLabel" fxFlex>
                    <mat-label>{{'audio.questions.Q1_Ear' | translate}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="q1_ear">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let e of ears" [value]="e.abbreviation">
                            {{e.type}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="q1_ear.hasError('required')">
                        {{'audio.questions.ResponseRequired' | translate}}
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

TS

```
private buildForm() {
    this.audioQuestionsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        q1: ['', [Validators.required]],
        q1_ear: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
        q2: ['', [Validators.required]],
        q2_often: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
        q3: ['', [Validators.required]],
        q3_when: [{ value: '', disabled: true}],
        q3_last: [{ value: '', disabled: true}],
        q3_freq: [{ value: '', disabled: true}],
        q4: ['', [Validators.required]],
        q4_desc: [{ value: '', disabled: true}],
        q5: ['', [Validators.required]],
        q5_gun: '',
        q5_rpy: '',
        q5_total: ''
    });
}

private setConditionalValidation() {
    this.audioQuestionsForm.get('q1').valueChanges.subscribe(
        (q1: string) => {
            this.audioQuestionsForm.get('q1_ear').clearValidators();
            this.audioQuestionsForm.get('q1_ear').disable();
            if (q1 === "Y") {
                this.audioQuestionsForm.get('q1_ear').setValidators([Validators.required]);
                this.audioQuestionsForm.get('q1_ear').enable();
            } 
            this.audioQuestionsForm.get('q1_ear').updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false});
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer shortly after posting this. Angular material has a css class mat-form-field-disabled. I just used this class and set display: none. If there is a cleaner way, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Two Ideas:

1. using `ngif` based on a variabel
2. i see you're using fxLayout, you can actually use `fxShow="{{variable}}"` to hide or show the element

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid having an individual variable for each question in this form, which is why I avoided idea #1. I actually was unaware of fxShow, so thanks for the information!

Since I have to use value changes on each of the questions to decide if I need to display their respective subquestions, I wanted to go with 1 way of controlling the front-end from the back end. In the .ts file, I just get the control from the form and set it to .disabled or .enabled and control the visibility with .mat-form-field-disabled.